# Объеденение ячеек с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: sql

Добрый день!
Начинаю изучать SQL
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно объединить ячейки с одинаковыми значениями raion. Заранее спасибо!

```
raion  reg              sum  
1      8035412365448    25.34  
1      18035412365448   34.35  
1      8035412365448    35.25
```

Comment: Какая БД вы используете? И как именно объединить - просуммировать остальные столбцы или как-то еще - приведите пример ожидаемого результата?

Comment: В общем пытаюсь создать запрос в Access. нужно объединить ячейки в столбце raion, чтобы убрать единицы

Comment: raion            reg                       sum  
1             8035412365448

Comment: добавьте это в вопрос

Comment: Вероятно, `SELECT [raion], MIN([reg]), SUM([sum]) FROM [table] GROUP BY [raion]` (при условии, что `reg` - числовое, конечно).

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать агрегатные функции (sum, max, min и т.д.).
Пример суммирования значения поля `sum` по району:

```
select raion, sum(sum) from table group by raion
```

Результат:

```
raion sum
1     94.94
```

Судя по вашему комментарию, вам еще нужен минимальный `reg`, тогда можно сделать:

```
select raion, min(reg), sum(sum) from table group by raion
```

**UPD:** из комментария я понял, что вы хотите получить что-то вроде этого:

```
raion | reg             | sum  
-------------------------------
1     | 8035412365448   | 25.34  
       ------------------------
      | 18035412365448  | 34.35
       ------------------------  
      | 8035412365448   | 35.25
-------------------------------
```

Средствами `sql` максимум, что вы сможете сделать - это оставить значение `raion` только в одной строке:

```
raion | reg             | sum  
-------------------------------
1     | 8035412365448   | 25.34  
-------------------------------
      | 18035412365448  | 34.35
-------------------------------  
      | 8035412365448   | 35.25
-------------------------------
```

но сами строки в этом столбце не объединятся - это нужно делать на стороне UI.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы остальные столбцы оставались неизменными, а  в raion обединить, оствить одну 1 во всём столбце.

Comment: Добрый вечер! Мне не нужно чтобы колонка sum суммировалась, а reg- выбиралось минимальное значение. нужно в этой таблице изменилась колонка raion.

Comment: @КузнецоваСветлана дополнил ответ